# Linking resources in php

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have following file structure for my app

```
/App
    /html
        404.html
        another.html
        other.html
    /css
        main.css
    .htaccess
    index.php
```

I am sending `other.html` file from `index.html` with `readfile()`.

> All html files shares `main.css`.

`index.html` looks like this

```
<html>
   <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/main.css">
   </head>
   <body>
      <a href="another.html">link</a>
   </body>
</html>
```

I am running this on XAMPP. With

```
    http://localhost/App
```

I'm able to retrieve index.html, but when I click on the link I'm getting `404.html`, as I wrote `another.html` and `../css/main.css` the server is looking for `http://localhost/App/another.html` and `http://localhost/css/main.css`. This leads to messed up CSS in 404.html and index.html

I attempt to solve this by replacing `../css/main.css` with `css/main.css`, but this leads to messed up CSS in 404.html whenever the error is encountered. Another attempt I tried is `/css/main.css`, but again no luck server is looking for `http://localhost/css/main.css`.

So, How do I link those file? Is there any configuration available in `.htacccess` that can say server to look `/` (root) as `/App`, so if there is any configuration then I can get everything works perfectly by saying `/css/main.css`, `/html/another.html`, and so on? Or any other suggestion?

Here is the video of the problem: https://youtu.be/Qg7K8gOdyW0

Answer (score 0):

Put inside you .htaccess file the following code:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/App/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /App/$1 [L,R=301]
```

in the index.html use next links:

```
/html/another.html
/css/main.css
```

Check this out:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oO1AHIOec3c

Comment: Oh! I forgot to mention I found this code in someone's question, but it's not working :(

Comment: Okay so I got it working, but I had to define different path for different files. Seems like I don't have to make a change in `.htaccess`. The changes I made: in `another.html` I change the path to relative path `../css/main.css`, while for `other.html` the path is `css/main.css`. 404.html is still not resolved for all path

Comment: That should work just fine, check out the video I've attached for you.

Comment: have you saw the video?

Comment: have you found a solution or question still relevant? actually, you don't need readfile(), put into index.php the default page, page you are trying to load with readfile

Comment: Actually I've some logic based on which I `readfile()`. But this path problem only occurs because of the XAMPP! As we can not determine root of the site with `/`  (we can but it will check for root of the server which is `htdocs`) but `/` did solved by problem on the server which I hosted